# How to flatten a group into a single tuple in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

From this:

```
(1, {(1,2), (1,3), (1,4)} )
(2, {(2,5), (2,6), (2,7)} )
```

...How could we generate this?

```
((1,2),(1,3),(1,4))
((2,5),(2,6),(2,7))
```

...And how could we generate this?

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(2, 5, 6, 7)
```

For a single row I know how to do. The problem is when I have to iterate over many rows AND manipulate internal groups at the same time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your question, I prepared the following file:

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,5
2,6
2,7
```

At first, I used the following script to get the input `r3` which you described in your question:

```
r1 = load 'test_file' using PigStorage(',') as (a:int, b:int);
r2 = group r1 by a;
r3 = foreach r2 generate group as a, r1 as b;
describe r3;
-- r3: {a: int,b: {(a: int,b: int)}}
-- r3 is like (1, {(1,2), (1,3), (1,4)} )
```

If we want to generate the following content,

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(2, 5, 6, 7)
```

we can use the following script:

```
r4 = foreach r3 generate a, FLATTEN(BagToTuple(b.b));
dump r4;
```

For the following content,

```
((1,2),(1,3),(1,4))
((2,5),(2,6),(2,7))
```

I can not find any helpful builtin function. Maybe you need to write your custom BagToTuple. Here is the builtin BagToTuple source codes: http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pig/pig/0.11.1/org/apache/pig/builtin/BagToTuple.java#BagToTuple.getOuputTupleSize%28org.apache.pig.data.DataBag%29

Comment: What if there are more than one field,1,2,3 
1,3,4
1,4,5
2,5,6
2,6,7
2,7,8 and we want the output as (1, 2,3,3,4,4,5)
(2, 5,6, 6,7, 7,8)

Answer (score 4):

In order to obtain :

```
((1,2),(1,3),(1,4))
((2,5),(2,6),(2,7))
```

You can do this :

```
r4 = foreach r3 {
    Tmp=foreach $1 generate (a,b);
    generate FLATTEN(BagToTuple(Tmp));
};
```

Comment: Amazing solution! why doesn't r4 = foreach r3 generate BagToTuple(b) work? It gives me ((1,4,1,3,1,2))
((2,7,2,6,2,5)), which seems irrational.

Answer (score 3):

There is no builtin way to convert a bag to a tuple.  This is because bags are *unordered* sets of tuples, so Pig doesn't know what order that the tuples should be set to when it is converted into a tuple.  This means that you'll have to write a UDF to do this.

I'm not sure how you are creating the `(1, 2, 3, 4)` tuple, but this is another good candidate for a UDF, even though you could create that schema with just the BagToTuple UDF.

**NOTE:** You probably shouldn't be turning anything into a tuple unless you know exactly how many fields there are.

**myudfs.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

@outputSchema('T:(T1:(a1:chararray, a2:chararray), T2:(b1:chararray, b2:chararray), T3:(c1:chararray, c2:chararray))')
def BagToTuple(B):
    return tuple(B)

def generateContent(B):
    foo = [B[0][0]] + [ t[1] for t in B ]
    return tuple(foo)
```

**myscript.pig**

```
REGISTER 'myudfs.py' USING jython AS myudfs ; 

-- A is (1, {(1,2), (1,3), (1,4)} ) 
-- The schema is (I:int, B:{T:(I1:int, I2:int)})

B = FOREACH A GENERATE myudfs.BagToTuple(B) ;
C = FOREACH A GENERATE myudfs.generateContent(B) ;
```