# Flatten inner bags in Pig

Tags: apache-pig, flatten

I have this:

```
(1,{(1,2,3)})

(4,{(4,2,1),(4,3,3)})

(8,{(8,3,4)})
```

I want this:

```
(1,1,2,3)

(4,4,2,1)

(4,4,3,3)

(8,8,3,4)
```

I found this post helpful, but couldn't get it to work:
[How to flatten a group into a single tuple in Pig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544602/how-to-flatten-a-group-into-a-single-tuple-in-pig)
This seems easy, but I am new to Pig.
Thanks in advance!

Edited to answer reo's question (thanks reo):

Before posting here on SO, I have tried to flatten that bag on my problem, only to get the following error (d is C in my example here):

```
    ERROR 2117: Unexpected error when launching map reduce job.

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias d
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:857)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:682)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:303)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:189)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:165)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:490)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:111)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.PigException: ERROR 1002: Unable to store alias d
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:956)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:919)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:832)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2117: Unexpected error when launching map reduce job.
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:322)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1270)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1255)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:952)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve error that occured when launching map reduce job: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecsHelper(PigOutputFormat.java:193)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:937)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:896)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:896)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:870)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Job.submit(Job.java:378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.startReadyJobs(JobControl.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:279)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:260)

        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$JobControlThreadExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(MapReduceLauncher.java:631)
        at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1874)
```

That was for my original problem. But now I tried the same thing on the reproducible example I used here, it works.

```
grunt> A = load 'my_location_on_HDFS' using PigStorage('|') as (a,b,c);
grunt> B = group A by a;
grunt> describe B;
B: {group: bytearray,A: {(a: bytearray,b: bytearray,c: bytearray)}}
grunt> dump B;
(1,{(1,2,3)})
(4,{(4,2,1),(4,3,3)})
(8,{(8,3,4)})
grunt> C = foreach B generate group, flatten(A);
grunt> dump C;
(1,1,2,3)
(4,4,2,1)
(4,4,3,3)
(8,8,3,4)
```

I guess I have to go take a closer look at my original data/situation.

Comment: Your question is not analogous to the one you linked to, and is just a straightforward use of `FLATTEN`. What have you tried that is not working?

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 4):

if you flatten the bag then you will get the desired output let us assume that your input above is B and you have got this by grouping a input A

just do a describe B;

```
Describe B;    
B: {group: bytearray,A: {()}}
```

Here A is a bag now if you can try something like

```
 C= foreach B generate group, FLATTEN(A);
```

C will have the values you wanted flattening a bag will result in separate rows